# Apache2 WSGI Flask app gives sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) unable to open database file

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, apache2

I get this error when I try to enter my Flask app running on WSGI and Apaceh2: [image]

The problem is, when I just run the Flask app and stop apache2, the error doesn't occur. But when I open Apache2, the error occurs. The file is located at `/var/www/html/meondashboard/configs`. This is how my `000-default.conf` file look like:
[image]

This is how I access the file:
[image]

How can I fix this? Do I need to restart my VPS? I would appreciate any type of help, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give `app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI']` full path. Then give `.db` file ownership to www-data.